# Legend colors not showing

Tags: jqplot

I followed the other question's answer and made absolutely sure jquery.jqplot.css is properly included but I still can't get the colors to show. I tried with a lot of rendereres (default, bar, funnel) and none of them work. I've even tried using the enhanced legend renderer to no avail.

This is the code I'm using to render the chart. Everything shows up okay except for the legend

```
plot2 = $j.jqplot('chart_palnie', [serie], {
seriesDefaults: {
    renderer:$j.jqplot.FunnelRenderer,
    rendererOptions:{
         sectionMargin: 8,
         widthRatio: 0.3,
         showDataLabels: true,
         dataLabels: serie_labeluri,
         dataLabelThreshold: 0
         //dataLabelFormatString: '%s, %d'
     }
 },
 legend: { 
    show:true, 
    location: 'e', 
    showLabels: true,
    showSwatch: true
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

include CSS file **jquery.jqplot.css** .. this solved for me

Answer (score 1):

try adding the placement option.  I also include the renderOptions, but that is mostly for IE support in my case.

```
legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'n',
            placement: 'inside',
            renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                numberRows: 1,
                disableIEFading: true
            }
        }
```

Comment: Same here...  Having the exact same problem methinks.